# Angular, ng-messages not showing inside angular material design dialog (md-dialog)

Tags: angularjs, dialog, angular-material

I'm working on a form to add a credit card in angularJS, with angular material (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/).

For all my other forms, i used ng-messages (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) to show validation errors, and it worked fine.

When i embded the form inside a md-dialog, my ng-messages are not displaying, the input became invalid, but no error displayed.
I've got the problem with basic validation directive and custom validation directive.

My dialog template :

```
<md-dialog>
<md-dialog-content style="max-width:800px;max-height:810px; ">
    <h2 i18n="add_card_button"></h2>
    <form name="form">
        <md-input-container>
            <label i18n="card_number"></label>
            <input  name="card_number"
                    type="text" 
                    ng-model="ctrl.newCard.cc_number"
                    class="md-input" 
                    required
                    card-number>
            <div ng-messages="form.card_number.$error">
                <div ng-message="cardNumber">test message</div>
                <div ng-message="required">test message 2</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        ...
    </form>
</md-dialog-content>
<div class="md-actions" layout="row">           
    <md-button ng-click="">
        <i18n>ok_button</i18n>
    </md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="cancel()" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <i18n>cancel_button</i18n>
    </md-button>
</div>
```

My dialog definition :

```
$mdDialog.show({
            controller : dialogController,
            controllerAs : "ctrl",
            bindToController : true,
            templateUrl : "creditCards/assets/templates/add_credit_card_dialog.html",
            parent : angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent : event,
            clickOutsiteToClose : true,
            locals : {
                cardTypes : vm.cardTypes
            }
        });
```

and my custom directive definition

```
angular
    .module('app.core')
    .directive("cardNumber", cardNumber);

/* @ngInject */
function cardNumber () {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        require : "ngModel"
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$validators.cardNumber = cardNumber;

        scope.$watch("cardNumber", function(){
            ngModel.$validate();
        });

        // Validate visa, mastercard, amex, concate new regex to validate more card
        var reg = new RegExp(/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|3[47][0-9]{13})$/);

        function cardNumber(modelValue){
            if(!modelValue){
                return true;
            }

            modelValue = modelValue
                            .replace(/-/g, "")
                            .replace(/\s/g, "")
                            .replace(/,/g, "");

            return reg.test(modelValue);
        }
    }
}
```

And a screenshot of the result where you can see the invalid field but no error message :
[image]

Comment: Any update on this? how you fixed this issue?

Comment: Nop never fixed it, project long gone

Answer (score 6):

There are two possible fixes detailed here: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8037

1. Make sure the ng-app directive is on the body tag of your page.
2. Remove the line `parent: angular.element(document.body)` from your $mdDialog.show() options.

Comment: I commented out the parent: angular.element(document.body) on my troubled script and boom!  It worked!   Thanks Casey!

Answer (score 4):

Have a try with

```
<div ng-messages="form.card_number.$error" md-auto-hide="false">
```

That fixed my similar issue

Comment: It looks this is a workaround when not using `md-input-container`, which is not OP scenario. I believe this is not a suitable answer to this question, it would fit better as a comment, because it's a shot in the dark (considering OP's situation), even though it might work for other scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make this work.

1. Add Angular Messages to the bower and index
2. Add the Module ngMessages to your app
3. On a md-input-container did this

```html
<md-input-container flex md-is-error="signupForm.emailAddress.$invalid && (signupForm.$submitted || signupForm.emailAddress.$dirty)">
  <label>Email Addresss</label>
  <input name="emailAddress" ng-model="registerInfo.emailAddress" type="email" required/>
  <div ng-messages="signupForm.emailAddress.$error" ng-if='signupForm.$submitted || signupForm.emailAddress.$touched'>
    <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
    <div ng-message="email">Enter valid email address.</div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
```

And for a custom directive I did this

```html
<div ng-messages="signupForm.verify.$error" ng-if='signupForm.verify.$dirty || signupForm.verify.$touched'>
  <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
  <div ng-message="passwordVerify">Doesn't Match.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No nothing pops in the dev console or in the browser

Comment: Hi @jbduzan did you try on your directive to use model.$setValidity() to setup validation on the model? BTW, I saw that you put a 'required' validation, does that show up? or both of the messages aren't showing?

Comment: Hi, no i didn't user model.$setValidity(), but i don't think it would work, the required directive don't show up either, and the other input all have "classic" directive and they don't show up too

Comment: maybe can you tried with <div ng-messages="form.card_number.$error" ng-if='form.card_number.$touched'>

Answer (score 2):

is it possible that you have two `form` tags?
if you copied the demos from Angular site,  you may have `form` inside `form`. this can cause this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Guys, I was facing the same issue. The problem in my case was that I hadn't removed an enclosing  tag from the sample md-dialog code. That was probably interfering with the messages.

Hope that helps you too.

Abhimanyu

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should catch error ng-model `form.cc_number.$error`, same code here:

```
<input name="card_number" type="text" class="md-input" card-number required ng-model="ctrl.newCard.cc_number">
<div ng-messages="form.cc_number.$error">
    <div ng-message="cardNumber">test message</div>
    <div ng-message="required">test message 2</div>
</div>
```